# Fail to quantize custom layer - Quantization Aware Training

Tags: python, tensorflow, quantization-aware-training

I'm following [Quantization aware training comprehensive guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/quantization/training_comprehensive_guide?hl=en) and struggling with QAT for custom layers, working with `tf=2.6.0`, `py=3.9.7`.
Below is a toy example of my problem:

I wrote a simple custom layer that implements Conv2D

```
class MyConv(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
'''costume conv2d'''

def __init__(self, filt=1, name=None, **kwargs):
    super(MyConv, self).__init__(name=name)
    self.filt = filt
    super(MyConv, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def get_config(self):
    config = super().get_config().copy()
    config.update({"filt": self.filt})
    return config

def build(self, shape):
    self.conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(self.filt, 1, padding="same")

def call(self, input):
    return self.conv(input)
```

I've created a small model with that layer, then recursively pass over its layers and annotates them using `tfmot.guantization.keras.quantize_annotate_layer` (each custom layer could have more custom sub-layers that needs to be quantized). Then I apply `tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_apply` to the annotated model. The result model consists of all the quantized layers, except of my custom layer, that had not been quantized.

[image: model summary attached]

I'll note that when I'm replacing the custom layer `MyConv` with the code below, as in the comprehensive guide, the quantization works.

```
def MyConv(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D):
    pass
```

Please help me solve this issue. Might be some issue with my `QuantizeConfig`?

Below is my full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot

class MyConv(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
'''costume conv2d'''

def __init__(self, filt=1, name=None, **kwargs):
    super(MyConv, self).__init__(name=name)
    self.filt = filt
    super(MyConv, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def get_config(self):
    config = super().get_config().copy()
    config.update({"filt": self.filt})
    return config

def build(self, shape):
    self.conv = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_annotate_layer(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(self.filt, 1, padding="same"))

def call(self, input):
    return self.conv(input)


def get_toy_model():
  input = tf.keras.Input((10, 10, 1), name='input')
  x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 3, padding="same")(input)
  x = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(x)
  x = MyConv()(x)
  for _ in range(2):
      y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 3, padding="same")(x)
      y = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(y)
  out = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 3, padding="same")(y)
  return tf.keras.Model(input, out, name='toy_Conv2D')

LastValueQuantizer = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantizers.LastValueQuantizer
MovingAverageQuantizer = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantizers.MovingAverageQuantizer


class DefaultCostumeQuantizeConfig(tfmot.quantization.keras.QuantizeConfig):
    # Configure how to quantize weights.
    def get_weights_and_quantizers(self, layer):
        return []

    # Configure how to quantize activations.
    def get_activations_and_quantizers(self, layer):
        return []

    def set_quantize_weights(self, layer, quantize_weights):
        pass

    def set_quantize_activations(self, layer, quantize_activations):
        pass

    # Configure how to quantize outputs (may be equivalent to activations).
    def get_output_quantizers(self, layer):
        return [tfmot.quantization.keras.quantizers.MovingAverageQuantizer(num_bits=8, per_axis=False, symmetric=False, narrow_range=False)]

    def get_config(self):
        return {}


def recursive_depth_layers(layer):
  for l in list(layer.__dict__.values()):
    if isinstance(l, tf.keras.layers.Layer):
        recursive_depth_layers(l)
        if isinstance(l, (
        tf.keras.layers.Dense, tf.keras.layers.Conv2D, tf.keras.layers.ReLU, tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU, tf.keras.layers.Activation)):
            ql = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_annotate_layer(l, DefaultCostumeQuantizeConfig())
            ql._name += "_" + l.name
            return ql


def apply_quantization(layer):
    # regular layer
    if isinstance(layer, (tf.keras.layers.Dense, tf.keras.layers.Conv2D, tf.keras.layers.ReLU, tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU,tf.keras.layers.Activation)):
      l = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_annotate_layer(layer, DefaultCostumeQuantizeConfig())
      l._name += '_' + layer.name
      return l
    if layer.__module__ == "__main__":
    # custom layer
      recursive_depth_layers(layer)
      l = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_annotate_layer(layer, DefaultCostumeQuantizeConfig())
      l._name += '_' + layer.name
      return l
  return layer

model = get_toy_model()
model.summary()

annotated_model = tf.keras.models.clone_model(model, clone_function=apply_quantization)
annotated_model.summary()

quantize_scope = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_scope
with quantize_scope({'DefaultCostumeQuantizeConfig': DefaultCostumeQuantizeConfig, 'MyConv': MyConv}):  
    quant_aware_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_apply(annotated_model)
    quant_aware_model._name += "_quant"
quant_aware_model.summary()
quant_aware_model.compile()
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I am also looking for a solution, facing same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately no, after some struggling I've abandoned it for the meanwhile